# How to make size charts popup for different products category..?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, configurable-product

I have created an attribute with `identifier -->size_chart_template`. with two option men and women. and printing it in `swatch.phtml` but no pop up is coming. button is showing in front end

```
      <!--START FOR SIZE CHART BUTTON-->
      <?php
      $sizeChartIcon= Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."size-charts/size-chart.gif"; ?>
      <a id="showchart">Size-Chart</a>
      <div id="size-chart" style="display:none;"> <?php echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_product->getAttributeText('size_chart_template'))->toHtml(); ?></div>
      <!--ENDS FOR SIZE-CHART BUTTON-->
```

Comment: Have you added any javascript for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to trigger the popup somehow.

Something like the below would work (assuming jQuery is available)

```
$(function() {
    $('#showChart').on('click', function() {
        $('#size-chart').css('display', 'block');
        //OR
        $('#size-chart').fadeIn();
    });
});
```